# Why won't col-sm-12 center itself?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

```html
 <div class="col-sm-12" style="text-align: center;">
                        <div class="col-sm-6" style="width: 180px">
                        <a href="#!" class="nk-btn nk-btn-outline nk-btn-color-main-3" style="padding:20px">TAKE A PEEK <i class="fa fa-youtube-play" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

                        </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6" style="width: 180px">
                <a href="#!" class="nk-btn nk-btn-x2  nk-btn-color-primary" style="padding:20px">GET STARTED</a>
                    </div>  

                    <!--col-sm-12 end--></div>
```

Comment: Firstly, two col-sm-6 will divide your row equally so no point of giving a width to it. And what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @bhavik patel When I didn't have the width, the buttons were spaced too far apart. I'm just trying to make the buttons perfectly centered. druvocals.com/1 you can see them

Comment: Bootstrap columns are floated to the left, which takes it out of the normal flow of the document.

Comment: GTN and center.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing my col-sm-12 with `<div style="text-align: center; width: 380px;margin: auto;">`did the trick

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the style="width:180px".